# Oracle SQL - how to insert multiple records

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to insert the following values "1)" to "150)" for 50 different records. How do I shorten the below into one line?

```
insert into p.p_assumptions (p_number, value) values (11, '1)');
insert into p.p_assumptions (p_number, value) values (11, '2)');
...
insert into p.p_assumptions (p_number, value) values (11, '150)');
```

Comment: Insert into what? An existing table? What are the **50 different records** into which you need to insert those values? Do you mean `11` is also generic, you must do this also for `p_number = 1`, `p_number = 2`, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is using connect by clause

```
insert into p_assumptions (p_number, value) 
select 11, level || ')'
from dual
Connect by level <= 150;
```

Comment: Just concatenate it to the number. Updated. Please check now

Answer (score 2):

A simple method: Take a table with at least 150 records. Then

```
insert into p_assumptions (p_number, value) 
select 11, to_char(rownum) || ')'
from table_with_at_least_150_records
where rownum <= 150;
```